# Get max value using stored procedures and join queries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i am fetching data from my `db` using `MS-Sql` `stored procedure` and showing it into my `crystal report` using a`sp.net`. what it does. 
1.get scheme name and scheme code from `sch_master` table 
2.join with `sch_detail` table 
3. inner join with `sch_releases` table to get last entered capital plus revenue releases amount(Max(quarter_id)) for that each and every particular scheme code. Here is `stored procedure` query.

```
ssm.SchemeName, ssm.SchemeCode, 
        (Select ISNULL(SUM(distinct ra.CapitalRelaseAmount + ra.RevenueReleaseAmount),0) from Sch_Releases ra where QuarterID=(Select MAX(QuarterID) from Sch_Releases as ra where ra.YearID=@YearID)) AS Releases
        FROM           
        dbo.Sch_SchemeMaster  AS ssm  INNER JOIN
        dbo.Sch_SchemeDetail AS ssd ON ssd.SchemeCode = ssm.SchemeCode INNER JOIN
        dbo.Sch_Releases AS ra ON ra.SchemeCode = ssm.SchemeCode and ra.YearID=@YearID 
        WHERE ssd.YearID=@YearID 
        GROUP BY  ssm.SchemeName, ssm.SchemeCode
        HAVING    (ssd.IsCompleted = 0) AND (ssd.IsDeleted = 0)
        order by  ssm.SchemeCode
```

but unlucky it it taking max entered values from the whole `table` not for related to each scheme code. please tell me what wrong in my query.
Thanks

Comment: We do not know the table structure and what result you are expecting? Atleast you should provide an expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ssm.SchemeName, 
    ssm.SchemeCode, 
    (Select ISNULL(SUM(ra.CapitalRelaseAmount + ra.RevenueReleaseAmount),0) from Sch_Releases ra where 
     ra.SchemeCode = ssd.SchemaCode AND ra.YearID = @YearId
     AND QuarterID=(Select MAX(QuarterID) from Sch_Releases as ra2 where ra2.SchemaCode = ra.SchemaCode and ra2.YearID=@YearID)
    ) AS Releases
FROM           
    dbo.Sch_SchemeMaster  AS ssm  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Sch_SchemeDetail AS ssd ON ssd.SchemeCode = ssm.SchemeCode 
WHERE 
    ssd.YearID=@YearID 
GROUP BY  ssm.SchemeName, ssm.SchemeCode
HAVING    (ssd.IsCompleted = 0) AND (ssd.IsDeleted = 0)
order by  ssm.SchemeCode
```